# Prompting an alert only after a gif is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, gif, prompt

This is how my code is suppose to work, if I click "button", I will go to display() where a full gif will be shown and only after the gif is shown, a prompt will appear. How do I do this?

My current code works opposite of what I want to achieve, which is, it prompts first then displays the gif.

```
//button
<input id="button" type="button" value="next" onClick="display()"/>

//javascript
<div id="display_panel">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function display(){
            if(gameStatArray[7][1][1]==1){
                var div = document.getElementById('display_panel');

                div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<div id="image_display"><img src="drawable/clip1.gif"/></div>';

                if (confirm("what do you want to continue?")) {
                    alert("yes");
                } else {
                    alert("no");
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance to whoever will answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I think all that is happening here is that when you inject into the document the following markup:

```
<img src="drawable/clip1.gif" />
```

The browser is firing off a request to the server to fetch the image. That may take only a few milliseconds, but in that time your script has continued and the `alert()` bit executed.

The simplest solution would be to have the `<img>` markup loaded in the document from the beginning, but use CSS to hide it initially. All your JavaScript needs to do is show the image, perhaps by adding a class.

```
document.getElementById('clip1').className = 'show-me';
```

Now the HTML looks like:

```
<img id="clip1" class="show-me" src="drawable/clip1.gif" />
```

The browser would have already fetched the image when the `<img>` tag was first rendered in the document. So no waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function display(){
    if(gameStatArray[7][1][1]==1){
        var div = document.getElementById('display_panel');

        // create the image
        var image = new Image();

        // action that happens after the image was loaded
        image.onload = function() {
            if (confirm("what do you want to continue?")) {
                alert("yes");
            } else {
                alert("no");
            }
        };

        // wrap image in image_display div
        var imageDisplay = document.createElement("div");
        imageDisplay.id = "image_display";
        imageDisplay.appendChild(image);

        // append image_display to display_panel
        div.appendChild(imageDisplay);

        // now set the src of the image
        image.src = "drawable/clip1.gif";
    }
}
```

Alternatively just preload it before appending it to the DOM:

```
function display(){
    if(gameStatArray[7][1][1]==1){
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {
            var div = document.getElementById('display_panel');

            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<div id="image_display"><img src="drawable/clip1.gif"/></div>';

            if (confirm("what do you want to continue?")) {
                 alert("yes");
            } else {
                alert("no");
            }
        };
        image.src = "drawable/clip1.gif";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did the same thing as my previous code. It displayed the prompt right after the button is clicked, then after the prompt is clicked, the gif started to show.

I think this happened because, the image is already loaded in the window so the prompt appeared, however, what I needed is to make the prompt appear after my 10sec gif finish showing. is there a way to do this? thanks. :D

Answer (score 0):

Add onload attribute to img tag:

```
//javascript
    <div id="display_panel">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function display(){
                if(gameStatArray[7][1][1]==1){
                    var div = document.getElementById('display_panel');

                    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<div id="image_display"><img src="drawable/clip1.gif" onload="showConfirm()"/></div>';
                }
            }

function showConfirm() {
    if (confirm("what do you want to continue?")) {
        alert("yes");
    } else {
         alert("no");
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="next" onClick="displayGif()"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function displaySurvey(){
    if(gameStatArray[7][1][1]==1){
        var div = document.getElementById('display_panel');
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<div id="image_display"><img src="drawable/clip1.gif"/></div>';
    return true;
    }

}


function showConfirm(){

    if(confirm("what do you want to continue?")){      
      alert("ok");
    }
    else {
      alert("KO");      
    }
}

function displayGif(){

    if(displaySurvey()){

        setTimeout(function() {showConfirm();}, 500);


    };

}

</script>
```